# Need Help Replacing Specific Paramater For Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parameters

Recently, I have been messing with javascript code for replacing an element once being clicked on 3 times and my issue is, I can't get the `data-id-slot-""` parameter replaced aswell. For this element `<ins data-ad-slot="4092520690">ins</ins>`. All i've managed is replace the innerText once clicked 3 times.

```
function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
  let count = 0;
  let callback = function() {
    count++;
    if (count >= 3) {           
      elem.replaceWith(newElem);
    }
  }
  ins1.click(callback);
}

const ins1 = $("ins[data-ad-slot]");

// pre-made second ins for future replacement
const ins2 = document.createElement('ins');
ins2.?? = '9020596432';
ins2.innerText = 'ins2';

replaceAfter3Clicks(ins1, ins2);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are confused at the difference between an HTML attribute, and a javascript object property

```
ins2.?? = '9020596432';
```

i think here you want something more like this

```
ins2.setAttribute("data-id-slot", "9020596432")
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the `attribute` of the element. You can set the attribute of an element with the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method of an element.

```
const ins2 = document.createElement('ins');
ins2.setAttribute('data-ad-slot', '9020596432');
ins2.innerText = 'ins2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since that is a [`data-` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*), you can access it by using the [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

```js
function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
  let count = 0;
  let callback = function() {
    count++;
    if (count >= 3) {           
      elem.replaceWith(newElem);
    }
  };
  ins1.click(callback);
}

const ins1 = $("ins[data-ad-slot]");

// pre-made second ins for future replacement
const ins2 = document.createElement('ins');
ins2.dataset.adSlot = '9020596432';
ins2.innerText = 'ins2';

replaceAfter3Clicks(ins1, ins2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ins data-ad-slot="">Placeholder</ins>
```

As the other answers have suggested you could also use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), but `dataset` is shorter, and in my opinion cleaner.

```
ins2.dataset.adSlot = '9020596432';
// vs
ins2.setAttribute('data-ad-slot', '9020596432');
```